# Getting residuals to a vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, formatting, regression, matlab-guide

Anybody knows how to get the residuals created by the following matlab code to a vector `A` ?

I tried to get the residuals by typing `r` at the command prompt but did not get the residuals

Thanks.

Code:

```
clc;
clear;

a0 = 0.05; a1 = 0.1; b1 = 0.85;
nu = randn(2300,1);
epsi = zeros(2300,1);
h = zeros(2300,1);

for i=2: 2300 
    h(i) = a0 + a1 * epsi(i-1)^2 + b1 * h(i-1)  ; 
    epsi(i) = nu(i) * sqrt(h(i));

end

ytlast=epsi(2300);
htlast=h(2300);

yt1 = zeros(2300,1);

for i=1: 2300 
    yt1(i) = epsi(i)*epsi(i);
end

yt=yt1(1301:2300);

order = 15;
m = arx(yt1, order);

r = resid(iddata([yt1(1:order);yt1]), m);
r = r(order+1:end);
```

Comment: What do you see when typing `r` at the command prompt?

Comment: Time domain data set with 2300 samples.
Sample time: 1 seconds                  
                                        
Outputs      Unit (if specified)        
   e@y1

Comment: I feel like `r` should just contain the residuals, after reading the help file for `resid`. I cannot test it right now, unfortunately. I don't have access to the toolbox at the moment.

Comment: When I typed r all I got was the above message. Could you please see to it tomorrow morning? It's a bit urgent. Thanks

Comment: I'll try to take a look at it tonight (I'm guessing I'm in a different time zone). I'm sure though, that there is someone else who will be able to give you an answer earlier.

Comment: Btw, have you tried looking at `r` before calling the last line: `r = r(order+1:end);` ?

Answer (score 4):

First use `get` to see what `r` has:

```
get(r)
ans = 
              Domain: 'Time'
                Name: ''
          OutputData: [2315x1 double]
                   y: 'Same as OutputData'
          OutputName: {'e@y1'}
          OutputUnit: {''}
           InputData: [2315x0 double]
                   u: 'Same as InputData'
           InputName: {0x1 cell}
           InputUnit: {0x1 cell}
              Period: [0x1 double]
         InterSample: {0x1 cell}
                  Ts: 1
              Tstart: []
    SamplingInstants: [2315x0 double]
            TimeUnit: 'seconds'
      ExperimentName: 'Exp1'
               Notes: {}
            UserData: []
```

Then, I assume you want to look at:

```
r.OutputData
```

to obtain the vector you wanted...